# POST variables not getting through AngularJS

Tags: ajax, angularjs, http-post

```
module2.factory('Ajax', function($http) {
        $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
        return {
        get : function(url, params){
            return $http.post(url, {
                params : params
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Made a factory to do some easy AJAX calls, but for security reasons I had to change the method to POST instead of GET (`$http.post` instead of `$http.get`), and now I dont get my data in my php files. Using `$_GET[]` did work when using `$http.get`, but now using `$_POST[]` when using `$http.post` I get an empty array. The `$http.defaults.headers.post[]` line was a solution in other stackoverflow topics, but it doesnt work for me.

What could be the problem?

Comment: The content-type that you have set is for POST where you send data in key-value format in body. Whereas if the params is a json object or array then angular wills serialize it as simple string. The issue may be due to content type. Do you need to send form-urlencoded data or json data?

Comment: I just need an array in PHP in $_POST, I have found out that when I use this code: `file_get_contents("php://input")` that it contains the JSON object. But I want to post it as form data I believe, so I can just var_dump my `$_POST` global.